# C# Error Selecting Table in OleDbCommand ...*LIBL not found

Tags: c#, sql, db2, oledb

I'm trying to make a connection to a DB2 Database sitting on our AS400 (ISeries).  I can connect to is successfully using the connection string but once I try to access the Tables I get this error: CPF9812: File SELECT in library *LIBL not found.

At this point I'm just trying to see if i can access the data in the table GLPCT.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace Testing_Connection_to_GLDBFA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionstring = "Provider=IBMDARLA.DataSource.1;Data Source=INFINIUM;Persist Security Info=True;Password=MyPassword;User ID=UserID;Initial Catalog=S06947A4;Default Collection=GLDBFA";
            string querySTring = "";
            DataTable schema;
            int i = 0;

            using( OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
            {

                querySTring = "SELECT * FROM GLPCT";
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(querySTring, cn);

                cn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
                    i++;
                    if (i == 20)
                        break;
                }

                cn.Close();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect to see the following error:

CPF9812: File **GLPCT** in library **USERID** not found.

As by default when using SQL naming the system will implicitly qualify unqualified table names with the user ID. For details, see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzqualun1.htm?lang=en)

It appears you are using an [OLE DB provider](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaik/rzaikoledbprovider.htm%23oledbprovider?lang=en) instead of the [.NET provider](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaik/rzaikdotnetprovider.htm?lang=en)

If you want to use the library list, you'll need use system naming and ensure that the library list is configured on the connection.

For the OLEDB providers, you want to set the *Library List* and *Naming Convention*

```
<connection>.Open('Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=SystemA;Library List=lib1,lib2, *USRLIBL;Naming Convention=1', 'Userid', 'Password');
```

For .NET provider, it's *LibraryList* and *Naming* properties.

Lastly, if you want to stay with the OLE DB provider, you might consider using the IBMDASQL instead of the IBMDARLA one.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, is Library list the name of the Database that the Tables reside in? I need to specify that, otherwise it just defaults to LIBL?

Comment: No, library is the traditional IBM i term for what other DBs call a `SCHEMA`.  See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzatc/rzatcterminology.htm) for other equivalents.   The library list is just a list of libraries that will be searched to find unqualified objects.  Most IBM i installs have just a single database.  Though you can have multiples.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think where I struggle most in reading about how to execute this is knowing which parameter I use to plug in under which variables. I have an SSIS Script that manages to connect to the AS400 and pull the Tables over to my Data Warehouse in SSMS. So i have a sense of what parameters work. I just struggle with plugging these settings into the right place.  For example the server is called 'S06947A4' , the Database is called 'GLDBFA' and then i have the names of the 4 Tables I want to pull over, and the UserID and Password.

Comment: I've been trying to find a way to execute this SSIS script via stored procedure in SSMS but I run into the same issue of understanding the parameters i need to plug in.

Comment: GLDBFA appears to be a library, aka schema, aka collection.  The actual DB name is probably S09647A4.   To see the DB name, you can use the WRKRDBDIRE command.

Comment: Ok cool, unfortunately i don't have direct access to the database/server. I will use your suggestions and see where i get. Thanks again.

Comment: Whoever does have access to the server should be able to tell you what you need.